# Attempting to view .Rda but receiving error: Object not found

Tags: r, dataframe, import

I am using a .Rda file for the first time. I'm pulling it off Github and have the project loaded into my files in R. I am able to move it into the Global Environment but when I use the following code:

```
load("~/Desktop/textCF/act_blue.Rda")
View(act_blue.Rda)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in View : object 'act_blue.Rda' not found
```

I looked at the environment and it said the data frame is character(empty). Is this an issue with how I am importing the data or is it an issue with the dataframe?

Comment: Use `print(load("..."))` to show the name of the object(s) being loaded. It’s probably not named “act_blue.Rda”

Answer (score 0):

An `*.Rda` file can contain one or many objects, which will carry the same name they had when they were saved. Let’s walk through this step by step.

`save()` is used to store a objects present in the current environment.

```r
a <- data.frame(a = 1)
b <- list(b = 2)
save(a, b, file = "a_b.Rda")
```

`load()` is used to import the `*.Rda` file into another or the same `R` session.

```r
rm(list = ls()) # This clears all objects from the environment - simulating a new session.
load("a_b.Rda")
```

We can now reference the imported objects with their original names.

```r
a
#>   a
#> 1 1
b
#> $b
#> [1] 2
```